# Taking details from a map and saving it into another?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a map like this

```
map<string, pair< pair<int, int>, string> >
```

what is the easiest way to get only the two strings and save into another map like this

```
map<string, string>
```

?
I mean is there another way other than something like this??

```
    map<string, pair< pair<int, int>, string> >  info;
    map<string, pair< pair<int, int>, string> >::iterator i;
    map<string, string> something;


    for(i=info.begin(); i!=info.end(); ++i)
        something[*i).first] = ((*i).second).second;
```

Comment: Another way than something that doesn't compile? Yes, probably... Um, why the `.c_str()`?

Comment: that was jus an old code snippet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd define a proper type:

```
struct Mapped
{
    int someSignificantName;
    int anotherName;
    std::string yetAnother;
};
```

There are almost no cases where `std::pair` is an acceptable solution
(except for quick hacks and tests).  Given that, you define a mapping
functional object:

```
struct Remap
    : std::unary_operator<std::pair<std::string, Mapped>,
                          std::pair<std::string, std::string> >
{
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> operator()(
            std::pair<std::string, Mapped> const& in ) const
    {
        return std::make_pair( in.first, in.second.yetAnother );
    }
};
```

, then use `std::transform`:

```
std::transform( in.begin(), in.end(),
                std::inserter( out, out.end() ),
                Remap() );
```

Comment: I like how you say "there are almost no cases where `std::pair` is an acceptable solution", then go on to use it heavily :P

Comment: @Tomalak: Ehm, he has to because of `std::map`. :P @James: Well, you need an `operator<` too.

Comment: @Xeo The only thing which needs an `operator<` is the `key_type`, and that's `std::string` in both cases.  And to both of you, I was aware of the irony when I posted.  But just because `std::map` is poorly designed doesn't mean your code has to be:-).  (In practice, I make intensive use of `std::pair` in quicky programs, to try out an idea, but only when forced to by `std::map` in production code.)

Answer (score 1):

```
map<string, pair< pair<int, int>, string> > map1 /* = ... */;
map<string, string> map2;

BOOST_FOREACH (const pair<string, pair< pair<int, int>, string> > >& it, map1) {
   map2[it.first] = it.second.second;
}
```

By the way, EWTYPE.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write simple for-loop that just works.

```
typedef pair<pair<int, int>, string> strange_pair_t;
typedef map<string, strange_pair_t> strange_type_t;
strange_type_t src_map;

map<string, string> dst_map;
for(strange_type_t::const_iterator it = src_map.begin(); it!=src_map.end(); ++it)
{
  dst_map.insert( make_pair( it->first, it->second.second ) );
}
```

The tricky way ("one-liner"):

```
std::transform( src_map.begin(), src_map.end(), inserter(dst_map, dst_map.end()), 
    boost::lambda::bind( 
        boost::lambda::constructor<pair<string,string>>(), 
        boost::lambda::bind( &strange_type_t::value_type::first, boost::lambda::_1 ), 
        boost::lambda::bind( &strange_pair_t::second, boost::lambda::bind( &strange_type_t::value_type::second, boost::lambda::_1 ) )
    )
);
```

C++0x way:

```
for_each( src_map.begin(), src_map.end(), [&dst_map](const strange_type_t::value_type& value) {
    dst_map.insert( make_pair( value.first, value.second.second ) ); } );
```